# Angular Schema Forms - copyValueTo in an Array

Tags: arrays, angular-schema-form

How do you use copyValueTo in an array?

For example:
    {
      "key": "myArray[].address.usstate",
      "copyValueTo": ["myArray[arrayIndex].address.state"]
    }

This inserts into myArray at arrayIndex (literally arrayIndex, not the index value).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is working from 1.0.0-alpha.4

It does not work prior to that as the array details were not made available in the scope processing copyValueTo when within an array.